# VB.net Borderless Form Maximize over Taskbar

Tags: vb.net, maximize, taskbar, maximize-window

When I maximize my borderless form, the form covers the entire screen including the taskbar, which I don't want it to do. I'm finding it very difficult to find a solution to my problem on the net, all I've come up with is the below code, which displays the taskbar for a short time, but then disappears and the form still takes up the entire screen.

```
Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.DoubleClick
    If e.Location.Y < 30 Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.ControlBox = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm starting to think the only way to solve my problem is to find the screen size height minus the taskbar height to get the form height, but I'm hoping there might be a simpler answer.

Comment: I'm starting to think the controlbox has no relevance to what I'm trying to do. Just assumed it did because the taskbar would appear for a sec when I put that in my code.

Comment: Oh, I also tried code to change the form to have a border, maximize then borderless again, but my form started to have melt down and stopped responding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the form's Load event to set its maximum size, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.MaximumSize = Screen.FromRectangle(Me.Bounds).WorkingArea.Size
End Sub
```

Maximizing it now restricts the size to the monitor's working area, which is the monitor size minus the taskbars.

Comment: Awesome, so glad there was a simple solution to my problem. Thanks so much, was searching the net for hours and couldn't find this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "working area" of the screen:

```
    Me.Bounds = Screen.GetWorkingArea(Me)
```

Comment: Also an awesome answer, works a charm. Thanks as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should better do this:

```
Me.MaximumSize = Screen.FromControl(Me).WorkingArea.Size
```

Because some users use multiple monitors. So if you use Hans Passant's way, when user maximize application to secondary monitor, application will get primary's monitor working area size and will look awful!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better way to solve your problem

```
  Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        With Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
            Me.SetBounds(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
        End With
    End Sub
```